# Filtering List which property is not included in property of another List

Tags: java, list, java-stream

```
public class Bill {
    private Long code;

    public Bill(Long code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    // setters and Getters
}

class Detail {
    private BillId billId;

    public Detail(BillId billId) {
        this.billId = billId;
    }
    // setters and Getters

}

class BillId {
    private Long number;
    private Long code;

    public BillId(Long number, Long code) {
        this.number = number;
        this.code = code;
    }
    // setters and Getters
}
```

Now I have

```
List<Bill> listBill = new ArrayList<>();
listBill.add(new Bill(1L));
listBill.add(new Bill(2L));
listBill.add(new Bill(3L));
listBill.add(new Bill(4L));
listBill.add(new Bill(5L));
listBill.add(new Bill(6L));


List<Detail> listDetail = new ArrayList<>();
listDetail.add(new Detail(new BillId(1000L, 10L)));
listDetail.add(new Detail(new BillId(1000L, 2L)));
listDetail.add(new Detail(new BillId(2000L, 30L)));
listDetail.add(new Detail(new BillId(2000L, 4L)));
listDetail.add(new Detail(new BillId(3000L, 50L)));
listDetail.add(new Detail(new BillId(3000L, 6L)));
```

Now I need a `new List` taken the items from `listBill`, where some item NOT MATCH with some item from `listDetail`

```
detail.getBillId ().getCode() not match with bill.getCode()
```

Expected List Sorry *for the New!*

```
newListBill.add(new Bill(1L)); 
newListBill.add(new Bill(3L));
newListBill.add(new Bill(5L));
```

Comment: Please fix `void BillId` and `List<Detail> listDetail`.

Comment: @tsolakp thanks do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using stream API:

```
listBill.stream()
.filter( b -> !listDetail.stream()
     .anyMatch( d -> d.getBillId().getCode() == b.getCode() ) )
.collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Comment: Sorry. I used your old example code. See the updated answer.

Comment: you can use `noneMatch` instead of `! anyMatch`

Answer (score 2):

There is more optimal solution with O(nlogn) complexity. Firstly get list of codes from details:

```
List<Long> codes = listDetail.stream()
            .map(detail -> detail.getBillId().getCode())
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And now do the filter with binary search (`codes` have been already sorted):

```
List<Bill> collect = listBill.stream()
            .filter(bill -> Collections.binarySearch(codes, bill.getCode()) < 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(collect);      // [Bill{code=1}, Bill{code=3}, Bill{code=5}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another variation of the existing answer with the use of `noneMatch` to avoid the explicit negation:

```
List<Bill>  output = listBill.stream()
        .filter( b -> listDetail.stream()
              .noneMatch(d -> d.getBillId().getCode().equals(b.getCode()))) // change here
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Sorry what about of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844376

Answer (score -1):

You could just iterate over both lists and compare the code variable (as I understand that's the only criteria you want to compare?):

```
    ArrayList<Bill> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Bill bill: listBill) {
       for(Detail detail : listDetail) {
          if(bill.getCode() == detail.getBillId().getCode() {
                result.add(bill);
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: the condition is, if not found!